# mhchem - bold part of equation typeset with \ce{}

Tags: mhchem

I'm trying to typeset a chemical equation using the `mhchem` package, and I want to bold just one part of the equation (to emphasize the product, in this case).

If I type `\ce{a A + b B -> c \textbf{C} + d D}`, then that produces *a* A + *b* B → *c* **C** + *d* D. That's perfectly fine, of course. But I cannot put any more complex chemical formulas within the `\textbf{}` command. If I enter, for example, `\ce{NH3(g) + HCl(g) -> \textbf{NH4Cl}(s)}`, ammonium chloride is typeset as NH4Cl(s), without the subscript.

I tried writing the subscript manually (`NH_4Cl`), but `$\ce{NH3(g) + HCl(g) -> \textbf{NH_4Cl}(s)}$` did not work, and instead gave me a bunch of errors (`missing $`, `extra } or forgotten $`, `missing {`, and `missing }`).

---

I'm pretty new here so I'm not exactly sure how this MWE thing works —  I don't have much that works, but as far as I can tell the code I was using to try things out seems to be pretty close to a MWE. Please let me know if I should provide anything else.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{a A + b B -> c C + d D}

\ce{a A + b B -> c \textbf{C} + d D}

\ce{NH3(g) + HCl(g) -> \textbf{NH4Cl}(s)}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `\textbf` is a hard break inside a `\ce`. What goes inside `\textbf`'s argument is not processed by the mhchem package.

This is the way to go.

```
\ce{NH3(g) + HCl(g) -> $\textbf{\ce{NH4Cl}}$(s)}
```

Use `$` to indicate that you want to escape mhchem parsing (mhchem does the correct guessing that `\textbf` and the next `{}` belong together, but using `$` is much clearer). Then use `\textbf`, then use `\ce` inside.

The `$` part (or the `\textbf` for that matter) might interrupt the mhchem flow. The succeeding `(s)` works fine, here, but you might not be always so lucky (for instance, a `$\textbf{4}$` would not be recognized as a number).

Comment: Approved! I should have used the same solution as you.

Answer (score 3):

Try

- using `\ce` in math mode (this *dose* change the output when you use a text font that looks different from the math font, or in headings, as commented by @mhchem) and
- using `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`

See this example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
$\ce{NH3(g) + HCl(g) -> \mathbf{NH_4Cl}(s)}$
\ce{NH3(g) + HCl(g) -> NH_4Cl(s)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using \ce in math mode *does* change the output when you use a text font that looks different from the math font, or in headings.

Comment: @mhchem thanks. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works flawlessly with `chemformula`, with the difference that the indeterminate coefficients should be typeset in math.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{$a$ A + $b$ B -> $c$ C + $d$ D}

\ch{$a$ A + $b$ B -> $c$ \textbf{C} + $d$ D}

\ch{NH3(g) + HCl(g) -> \textbf{NH4Cl}(s)}

\end{document}
```

[image]